# Can't download 3D-mesh file using provided link

Tags: amazon-s3, autodesk-forge, autodesk-realitycapture

I use Autodesk's Forge Reality Capture API for photogrammetry. All the process from generating photoscene to uploading receiving the download link works perfect, but at the last step, when I need to download `.obj` file from AWS S3 bucket, it says that I need some extra credentials for access.

Here is the link that I receive:

```
https://adsk-rc-photofly-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/3.0.0/OUT/MRm2mQqlNM32VEYA4JR8lBcvbpc4b6yoMMB0VRmUhL4-111086152-hsiHVHnE09lDPK3qpupouDsBX21HuLkSqrTeGkkUUNs/100000000/newscene5.obj.zip?response-content-disposition=attachment3            0.000000ilename-21166991523.0.00.000000OUT0.000000MRm2mQqlNM32VEYA4JR8lBcvbpc4b6yoMMB0VRmUhL4-2088566701-hsiHVHnE09lDPK3qpupouDsBX21HuLkSqrTeGkkUUNs0.0000001000000000.000000newscene5.obj.zip&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEEkaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQDA6X4LOJ3wRlgpuZffq82OUldYJwKx11io4VGJGeg4FQIhAM3dpIpS1i73JOnhVJ54LyaWCXkWbK3lt72Ee7troeJuKrQDCDIQABoMNDM2OTA3NDM4MjM2IgwLzfNFHTdpsXJO4ygqkQMhqjDmXFZM1FNzCnbM0Jr3Z0ydYNMSRQAXkOUYKy2lxRSW0yrZLgduT0cikAFPecrw0.0000009xE7qwPIutP0E8zqH0.0000002N1g1GvkV0KOLANczmddmqZO95wvcXdecSszZtjyf4VliczdEdOUBA9BncH7xaNYPbE2L7gN8z0.000000LB92eUwttWV8hHIsw8jDdDzH2xL8hPzj5JNqKjnOG4Fv68zGelaSqQwldjeeSir8B8woZxczskyhLfEN8vn1raz9JIN5Jnt1khvm92CfK6CocfC56WC472wJDU0.0000002vrDYDwjBlTNdivxN2soFPnZRJflxPhtMZONtw8XfHPC2
```

Is there an easy way to download that file?

Comment: The credentials are embedded in the link itself. The link you posted seems to be malformed, for example, the part that says `attachment3            0.000000ilename` is strange. As Denis mentioned below, are you perhaps accidentally modifying the link in your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your link is trimmed (perhaps by your application).

I just runned a scene and compared my results with your link and note the difference:

yours:

```
https://[....]/newscene5.obj.zip?
response-content-disposition=attachment[...]newscene5.obj.zip&
X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&
X-Amz-Security-Token=I[...]2
```

versus mine:

```
https://[....]/some_scene_name.obj.zip?
response-content-disposition=attachment[...]some_scene_name.obj.zip&
X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&
X-Amz-Security-Token=I[...]D&
X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&
X-Amz-Credential=ASIA[...]_request&
X-Amz-Date=20200820T193456Z&
X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&
X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Signature=a3[...]f7a
```

As you can see, you are missing a lot of things.

Check in curl or Postman the same results, to identify why you get the trimmed link.

for example, here is my full Postman result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! You were absolutely right - for some reasons Xcode was trimming the output link Changing output format helped me. Thanks!